# Is it possible to assign different images on instances in geometry nodes?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, shaders

I have all the things ready like images, mask, as well as geometry node. I'm confused at this point that how can I assign different images from **Shader** to **Geometry Node's** instances. Attached image will give you better idea what I'm looking for. The source file is also attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another answer if you maybe want to combine your images in a grid. In my case I have 6 images in a 2 × 3 grid (2 columns, 3 rows) like this:

[image: image grid]

Then I can use the index of the instances (see the *Geometry Nodes* nodetree from my previous answer below) as attribute in the *Shader Editor* to move the UV map of the instances according to their index. Then the images are going to be distributed on the instances from bottom left to top right, row by row.

[image: nodetree]

Now the *Mapping* node needs the *Location* and *Scale* data depending on the columns and rows of the image grid. Let's start with the *Scale* because it is the easiest: I take a *Combine XYZ* node where Z scale can be 1 or anything else, for X and Y the values are:

$$X=\frac{1}{columns},\quad Y=\frac{1}{rows}$$

The *Location* needs to be always the X scale multiplied by the column index (starting at 0), in this case with 2 columns either 0 or 1. So that would be:

$$(index \bmod columns)\cdot\frac{1}{columns}$$

For the Y location you need the row index (0, 1, 2) multiplied by the Y scale or as a formula:

$$\left\lceil\frac{index}{columns}\right\rceil\cdot\frac{1}{rows}$$

The formulas look more complicated then they are. Using these in a shader for the UV mapping you can now place each image on a plane. If there are less instances then images, only as much images as instances are shown. When there are more instances then images, the images are repeated. For the images it does not matter if the instances are distributed in a grid, a row or whatever.

[image: shader with grid image]

For the "random" distribution of images like mentioned in the comments, instead of using the instance index in the *Store Named Attribute* you could use a *Random Value* node with *Min* = 0 and *Max* = instances - 1.

By the way the shader setup would also work with all images combined in a single row by using the amount of images as columns and row = 1, but with a single row the shader setup can be done easier since you only need mapping values for X location and scale (or Y location and scale if you arrange the images in a single column):

[image: shader for single row images]

Here is an example of randomly placing the 6 images on 40 planes. As soon as you have arranged the images in a grid, it does not matter how many planes you want them to be placed on:

[image: more image planes]

Another example where the 6 images are randomly distributed on 642 planes instanced on an icosphere:

[image: planes on icosphere]

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if there is a smarter way yet,but you can do it by comparing the named attribute in shader by a *Math* node set to *Greater Than* and using this as mix factor in a *Mix Color* node to switch between the images.

First of all, in my example (and I guess in your case shown in the question as well), there is no need for a *Realize Instances* node. For simplicity I only have three images here, a *Mesh Line* with three points on which I instance a plane which should show the images. I store the index of the instance in a named attribute "index" (how fancy).

[image: GN nodetree]

Now there are three instances having the indices 0, 1, 2. In the shader I get them by using an *Attribute* node set to *Type: Instancer* and of course the *Name* "index". Then I compare the output in *Greater Than* node to 1 and plug the result in a *Mix Color* node. If the index is 0, the result is false and the image in the first input will show.

If the index is 1 or 2, the result is true and the *Mix Color* node will output the image from the second input. The output of this mix node goes into the first input of a second *Mix Color* node, the factor will be a *Greater Than* node checking if the index is greater than 1. If not (0 or 1), then the second mix node outputs whatever is in the first socket (either image 0 or 1), if the index is 2 it will show the second input where the third image is plugged in.

[image: material shader]

That's not the most efficient way I guess especially if you have more images, but unfortunately in the *Shader Editor* there is no *Collection Info* node for images to pick one directly by the index.

Comment: Your idea is great. It will take too much time for my images. I don't have only 3 images. I'll be waiting for more answers. Thank you

Comment: @Muzammil12 I thought at first there might be a way with an image sequence and picking by frame number, but this did not work. Perhaps you could make one large image collage with all images in a grid and then place the UVs somehow according to the index...

Comment: That would be too time consuming.

Comment: @Muzammil12 Okay, good to know then I can stop working on my second elaborate (to explain, not to produce as shader) answer. If having a simple shader sorting the UVs and the only thing you need is creating a grid of images is also too time consuming (I'm pretty sure there is software out there which can do that) then I fear there might not be a satisfying answer for you.

Comment: For idea, I'm have more than 300 planes and 10+ images. I'm going to add these 10 images to 300+ planes randomly. I hope you will generate a better result with it. Thank you

Comment: @Muzammil12 10 images on 300 planes would not have been a problem with my new setup (unless you do not even want to put the effort of combining 10 images together), but you never mentioned "randomly" before. So then I would simply store the random value as atrribute instead of the index. But okay, you do not want to put any work in it, I understand.

Comment: I'm sorry for not mentioning the randomly. Thank you for the answer. It worked